# ValueBox dinâmico R

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

bom dia!

Estou fazendo o meu primeiro Dashboard no R utilizando o pacote flexdashboard no R markdown e Shiny.

Ao selecionar o filtro no (SelectInput) o meu (Value Box) fica estático, como faço para deixar ele dinâmico ao selecionar o filtro?

Abaixo função utilizada...

```
#Funcao para chamar o Value boxes
TempMedio = function(...) return(round(mean(df$TempMax), digits = 1))

a = TempMedio()
valueBox(a, icon = "ion-thermometer", color = "#FF8C00")
```

Comment: Você está usandoa função `reactive`, certo?

Comment: Já viu a função `renderValueBox`?

Comment: Tomás, sim vi essa função, mas não consegui aplicar...

Comment: Seu exemplo não está completo, então não dá para entender porque ela não funcionaria...

Comment: De todo modo, coisas dinâmicas devem fazer referência a lista `input`, onde as interações do usuário estarão disponíveis para usar nos cálculos/condições.